# Converting a javascript array to HTML list when the array is a variable (causing type error)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want my javascript function to convert an array from my HTML document into an HTML list in a separate document. However, I am encountering problems with this and think it might be because the array isn't being recognised.

My HTML document is a digital edition in which each word is enclosed in an `<a>` element, which has attributes. One of these attributes (`@abbr`) has been compiled by my XSLT transformation to resemble a javascript array; i.e.

```
<a id="123" onclick="myFunction(this.id)" abbr="['x', 'y', 'z']">word</a>
```

As part of my javascript function (triggered by clicking on the word), I want to present x, y, and z as rows in an unordered list. This is what I have at the moment:

```
    function myFunction(id) {
var el = document.getElementById(id);
var abbrArray = el.getAttribute('abbr');
var abbrList = '<ul></ul>';
var abbrListItems = abbrArray.join('</li><li>');
var abbrListFull = abbrList.innerHTML = '<li>' + abbrListItems + '</li>';
}
```

This is what the `abbrListFull` variable should stand for:

```
<ul>
<li>x</li>
<li>y</li>
<li>z</li>
</ul>
```

The function goes on to create a table and place the `abbrListFull` variable as the inner HTML of one of the cells.

However, the function fails because of "Uncaught TypeError: abbrArray.join is not a function". Can anyone explain what is causing this problem and how to fix it?

I realise that this error is sometimes due to a function being performed on the wrong type of object. Alerting `abbrArray` produces "['x', 'y', 'z']", which looks like an array, but I am wondering if there is something else I need to do to make this recognizable as an array within the function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAttribute` returns a string, which in your case happens to look like an array. For the particular example you have given, you could use the `.match` method of strings to convert to an array e.g.

```
abbrArray = el.getAttribute('abbr').match(/(\w+)/g);
```

This will convert a string that looks like

```
"['abbr1', 'abbr2', 'abbr3']"
```

into

```
Array [ "abbr1", "abbr2", "abbr3" ]
```

which you will then be able to do a join on.

Comment: Thanks! That works nicely. And it is interesting to know that what resembles an array is not necessarily an array...

Comment: Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with Nick's answer, in terms of the original question.

However, the data compiled under `@abbr` (i.e. x, y, and z), in my case, were actually URLs. I didn't mention this, as it didn't seem to be relevant, but it actually was. Using the accepted solution above on the URLs split them into an array at each "." and "/". To achieve the desired outcome (an array of URLs), I used the following:

```
abbrArray = el.getAttribute('abbr').split(" ");
```

after changing my XSLT transformation so that the `@abbr` attribute contained simply "x y z".